# Allow only email for UITextField input Swift iOS8

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I try to ask users to sign up the member with their email address as the username.
In the textfield of username, I have changed the keyboard type into "Email Address". But, how do I restrict users enter email address into the textfield.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Yes, I didn't find yesterday. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this code to validate email address:

```
@IBOutlet weak var emailText: UITextField!
@IBAction func logIn(sender: AnyObject) {

    let validLogin = isValidEmail(emailText.text)
    if validLogin {
        println("User entered valid input")
    } else {
        println("Invalid email address")
    }
}

func isValidEmail(testStr:String) -> Bool {
    let emailRegEx = "[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,64}"
    let range = testStr.rangeOfString(emailRegEx, options:.RegularExpressionSearch)
    let result = range != nil ? true : false
    return result
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It works for me very well.

Comment: Happy to help you..:)

Answer (score 1):

Although it's a duplicate, but may I suggest using [SSValidationTextField](https://github.com/shamasshahid/SSValidationTextField)
It's an API that I wrote sometime back. 
Sample code looks something like

```
var phoneValidationTextField = SSValidationTextField(frame: CGRectMake(200, 200, 150, 50))
phoneValidationTextField.validityFunction = self.isValidPhone
phoneValidationTextField.delaytime = 0.5
phoneValidationTextField.errorText = "Incorrect Format"
phoneValidationTextField.successText = "Valid Format"
phoneValidationTextField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.RoundedRect
self.addSubview(phoneValidationTextField)
```

And a typical validity function looks like

```
func isValidEmail(stringValue: String) ->Bool {
    let emailRegEx = "[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}"
    let emailTest = NSPredicate(format:"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegEx)
    return emailTest.evaluateWithObject(stringValue)
}
```

It takes care rest of validation itself.